# Groping Pages Per Department Option

Tags: pages

Is it possible to create groups for pages?  We are a government agency and we have several departments.  With so many departments there is a strong possibility that the pages will get confusing to use.  For example, all the different departments have a Contact page.  It would be nice to have Department_1, Department_2, Department_x, and each one having a Contact page.  So the user would first go into the Department_2 group and edit the Contact page for it.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The most simple way to solve this and related problems is using a multi-site setup.

Comment: you can use custom posts for each department, or add category support for pages

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add categories to pages.

You can use a plugin for that:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-category-to-pages/

Or if u are using a child theme, insert this code in functions.php in your child theme directory:

```
function myplugin_settings() {  
    // Add tag metabox to page
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'page'); 
    // Add category metabox to page
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');  
}
 // Add to the admin_init hook of your theme functions.php file 
add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_settings' );
```

Another way is to create custom posts. there are plugins for this as well.

The difference is that a post can have multiple categories, while custom posts are like posts, or pages. in fact you are adding another post type beside the default posts and pages.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is to be able to visually manage the pages in the Wordpress admin UI, so categories or custom post types won't help with that I guess?

I did a quick search and found a plugin called [Nested Pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-nested-pages/) which looks like it lets you create the visual structure you want in the WP Admin UI for pages, however I don't know if it would do anything else that is undesireable for you. Might be worth a go before you invest the time in Multisite, which is a good option if you understand the implications of it:

[image]